# Nuxt JS i18n / multilingual with headless CMS

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

Just started playing around with Nuxt (and Vue in general) so please forgive me if I am overlooking something obvious here.

I am trying to set up a multilingual site using DatoCMS as my content source.

I have set up the nuxt-i18n plugin, translated routes and all is working fine. Now in a page, I need to switch the content depending on the current locale and I have only found examples with the content being stored locally in json files etc.

I found a workaround which can't be the way it is supposed to be:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="this.$metaInfo.htmlAttrs.lang === 'de-DE'">{{homepage.germanTitle}}</div>
    <div v-else>{{homepage.englishTitle}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  apollo: {
    homepage: gql`
      {
        homepage {
          id
          title
          englishTitle: title(locale: en)
          germanTitle: title(locale: de)
        }
      }
    `
  }
}
</script>
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this is the right way to do it:

```
<div>
<template v-if="$i18n.locale === 'en">{{homepage.englishTitle}}</tempate>
<template v-else>{{homepage.germanTitle}}</tempate>
</div>
```

You shouldn't use `this` inside of template, check i18n API to see where you can get data for your condition (in this case I use $i18n.locale), use template instead of div (or ternary operator, in order to avoid markup issues in some cases).

BUT, if its possible with graphql, I'd better do the following:

```
homepage {
     id
     title: {
       en: title(locale: en)
       de: title(locale: de)
     }
}
```

template:

```
<div>{{ homepage.title[$i18n.locale] }}</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately DatoCMS doesn't return the data in that way even though it would be perfect that way. I guess I will have to try a few workarounds to find the cleanes approach. Does the v-if v-else way hurt performance or anything in any way if all pages and templates are set up that way?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should fetch the data differently from GraphQL.

I would do something like:

```
query {
  homepage(locale: $locale) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

From DatoCMS docs: https://www.datocms.com/docs/content-delivery-api/localization

But then you need to decide how to pass the `$locale` variable. That depends on how you prefer. I would check here: https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#simple-query the alternative options that you have.